# Not able to find bin folder in Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: maven, testng, classpath, bin, lib

To run testng test  from command prompt  i have to set  the class path  and run tests
C:\newworkspace\SeleniumSample>set classpath = C:\newworkspace\SeleniumSample\bin; C:\newworkspace\SeleniumSample\lib*

C:\newworkspace\SeleniumSample>java org.testng.TestNG testng.xml

My maven project doesn't contain bin or lib folders.I manually created lib folder  and added jars to this folder.Any help would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Maven does not have a bin folder as all the dependent JAR files mentioned in the POM file are downloaded and saved in the ${user.home}/.m2 folder. If you want to trigger TestNG Test case from command line you can use the Maven Surefire plugin for TestNG by configuring the plugin in POM.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.19.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
                <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${testNGXMLFile}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
                <properties>
                    <property>
                        <name>usedefaultlisteners</name>
                        <value>true</value>
                    </property>
                </properties>
                <workingDirectory>${basedir}</workingDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then from the command prompt you can trigger using maven

```
mvn clean test -DtestNGXMLFile=src\test\resources\testng.xml
```

More information on [apache maven-surefire-plugin for testng](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/testng.html)